# Identifying maximum stretch of values between two null values in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with datetime and a column. I have to find maximum stretch of values between two null values.In example below,the maximum stretch of values between two null values is 4 i.e from timestamp '02-01-2018 00:05 to 02-01-2018 00:20'

Below is my sample data:

```
Datetime            X
01-01-2018 00:00    1
01-01-2018 00:05    Nan
01-01-2018 00:10    2
01-01-2018 00:15    3
01-01-2018 00:20    2
01-01-2018 00:25    Nan
01-01-2018 00:30    Nan
01-01-2018 00:35    Nan
01-01-2018 00:40    4
02-01-2018 00:00    Nan
02-01-2018 00:05    2
02-01-2018 00:10    2
02-01-2018 00:15    2
02-01-2018 00:20    2
02-01-2018 00:25    Nan
02-01-2018 00:30    Nan
02-01-2018 00:35    3
02-01-2018 00:40    Nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want maximum count of stretch between two null values, you can use `Series.isnull()` to find the indexes of null values and the `list comprehension` to find the difference:

```
indexes = df[df.X.isnull()].index         
max([(indexes[i+1] - indexes[i]-1) for i in range(len(indexes)-1)])
>> 4
```

If  you also want the time stamps:

```
indexes = df[df.X.isnull()].index          
max_nulls = max([((indexes[i+1] - indexes[i]-1), indexes[i], indexes[i+1]) for i in range(len(indexes)-1)], key = lambda x: x[0])
max_nulls
>>(4, 9, 15)

df.loc[max_nulls[1]:max_nulls[2]]
     Datetime             X
9   02-01-2018 00:00    NaN
10  02-01-2018 00:05    2.0
11  02-01-2018 00:10    2.0
12  02-01-2018 00:15    2.0
13  02-01-2018 00:20    2.0
14  02-01-2018 00:25    NaN
```

If you just want the timestamps with max stretch of non nulls values between them, use:

```
df.loc[[max_nulls[1], max_nulls[2]]]
    Datetime             X
9   02-01-2018 00:00    NaN
14  02-01-2018 00:25    NaN
```

or

```
df.loc[[max_nulls[1]+1, max_nulls[2]-1]]

      Datetime           X
10  02-01-2018 00:05    2.0
13  02-01-2018 00:20    2.0
```

Comment: @ Mohit Motwani thanks a lot  for your input. However, I need timestamp as well for that maximum stretch of not null values.